# Which S3 manager creates '_$folder$' files for pseudo-folders?

Tags: amazon-s3, directory

I know that S3 has no folders, and I'm working with an inherited application that has some buckets filled with folder_name_$folder$ items. I know that a lot of different tools use these files, or other folder sigils, depending on the tool, to help represent 'folders' to various visual interfaces. I'm wondering which one uses this particular convention.

I'd like to remove them so that my various rake tasks that run down lists of files can go faster, but I'm afraid I'll end up breaking some tool that someone else in the company uses. Can anyone say which tools create these keys, and what functionality, if any, removing them would break? S3fox? The main AWS console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the _$folder$ folders are created with S3Fox, AWS Console doesn't create them. you can safely delete them if you like

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 7):

They are also created by Hadoop S3 Native FileSystem ([NativeS3FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/NativeS3FileSystem.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The $folder$ is created the hadoop and spark application during the file movement process.

You can remove them using s3 command

```
 aws s3 rm s3://path --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*\$folder\$"
```

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be created by 3Hub as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter this issue when I was creating Athena Partition when there was no such key in S3. These files can be safely removed.

Please check also here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/